# How to fix c# desktop application form resizing or scaling issue for Windows 11

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application, autoscaling, windows-11

I have a C# desktop application which is developed in dot net framework 4.6.2. This application is working finr in Win 10. But when same application is run in Win 11, all form controls are disturbed. Like few buttons are totally hidden. Is there any global fix? I don't want to reposition and resize the forms  and controlls again for the whole application.

Comment: Which Fonts are you using?

Comment: Is it WinForms?

Comment: [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: [Automatic scaling in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/automatic-scaling-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is because the Windows 11 computer has a different screen DPI setting. Winforms is notoriously bad at scaling with any setting other than 100%. If you cannot run 100% all the time, then you will have to do some coding magic to detect DPI setting and adjust margins and padding... Or you could redo your UI in WPF, which scales properly at any setting.

Some possible avenues to explore if you rebuild to .NET 4.7+:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8